Laptop Special Function Keys Not Recognized
Recently I bought a Lenovo Yoga 7 2-in-1 14" Ryzen 7 (83DK000BUS) and installed PopOS on it. Everything is working fine, except the mic mute and airplane mode keys do not work. The buttons do work in Windows 11, and they do not work in other Linux OS's I've live-booted (i.e. EndeavourOS).
Using sudo evtest on the Ideapad Extra buttons event/device shows the key presses are registered, but both keys are assigned keycode 240, which is KEY_UNKNOWN (full output at end of post). I am trying to figure out how to map the the keypresses to the correct keycodes.
I created /lib/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb with the following content:
evdev:name:Ideapad extra buttons:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:br*:svn*:pn*:pvr*:rvn*:rn*:rvr*:cvn*:ct*:cvr*:sku*:*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_13f=rfkill                                 # airplane mode switch (toggle all wireless devices)
 KEYBOARD_KEY_13e=f20                                    # micmute
 KEYBOARD_KEY_42=f23
 KEYBOARD_KEY_43=f22

The evdev name is recognized since evtest output recognizes the keyboard key assignments (evdev name extrapolated from sudo udevadm test /sys/class/input/event7 output). The rest of the content is copied out of /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb which is a default file. I changed the KEYBOARD_KEY assignments for rfkill and f20 from the default to the key values provided by evtest (13e and 13f).
Then I ran sudo systemd-hwdb update && sudo udevadm trigger, but the keys still do not work.
I ran sudo udevadm test /sys/class/input/event7 and can see that my assignments are being processed, but there are also errors for my entries (full output at end of post):
Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x13e, and key code 190: Invalid argument
and
Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x13f, and key code 247: Invalid argument
I am interested in figuring out why there's an error with my .hwdb file or another way to enable these buttons.
Full output of evtest when pressing the mic mute button (located on the F4 key):
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "Ideapad extra buttons"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 148 (KEY_PROG1)
    Event code 149 (KEY_PROG2)
    Event code 186 (KEY_F16)
    Event code 190 (KEY_F20)
    Event code 192 (KEY_F22)
    Event code 193 (KEY_F23)
    Event code 202 (KEY_PROG3)
    Event code 203 (KEY_PROG4)
    Event code 212 (KEY_CAMERA)
    Event code 227 (KEY_SWITCHVIDEOMODE)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
    Event code 247 (KEY_RFKILL)
    Event code 364 (KEY_FAVORITES)
    Event code 445 (?)
    Event code 446 (?)
    Event code 562 (?)
    Event code 634 (?)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1724253963.688247, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 13e
Event: time 1724253963.688247, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 1
Event: time 1724253963.688247, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724253963.688277, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 0
Event: time 1724253964.688277, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------

Full output of evtest when pressing the airplane mode button (located on the F8 key):
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "Ideapad extra buttons"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 148 (KEY_PROG1)
    Event code 149 (KEY_PROG2)
    Event code 186 (KEY_F16)
    Event code 190 (KEY_F20)
    Event code 192 (KEY_F22)
    Event code 193 (KEY_F23)
    Event code 202 (KEY_PROG3)
    Event code 203 (KEY_PROG4)
    Event code 212 (KEY_CAMERA)
    Event code 227 (KEY_SWITCHVIDEOMODE)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
    Event code 247 (KEY_RFKILL)
    Event code 364 (KEY_FAVORITES)
    Event code 445 (?)
    Event code 446 (?)
    Event code 562 (?)
    Event code 634 (?)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1724254154.518907, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 13f
Event: time 1724254154.518907, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 1
Event: time 1724254154.518907, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724254154.518939, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN), value 0
Event: time 1724254154.518939, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------

Full output of sudo udevadm test /sys/class/input/event7:
This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

Trying to open "/etc/systemd/hwdb/hwdb.bin"...
Trying to open "/etc/udev/hwdb.bin"...
=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          249
file size:        11587386 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            2378850 bytes
nodes              9208456 bytes
Load module index
Found cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/, full unified hierarchy
Found container virtualization none.
Loaded timestamp for '/etc/systemd/network'.
Loaded timestamp for '/usr/lib/systemd/network'.
Parsed configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Parsed configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/network/73-usb-net-by-mac.link
Created link configuration context.
Loaded timestamp for '/etc/udev/rules.d'.
Loaded timestamp for '/usr/lib/udev/rules.d'.
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/01-md-raid-creating.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/39-usbmuxd.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-vm-hotadd.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-apport.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/56-lvm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-autosuspend.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-block-pop.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-block.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-ffado.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-fido-id.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-input-id.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-inputattach.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane1.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-pcmcia.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-sensor.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-steam-input.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-steam-vr.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-tpm-udev.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gnome-settings-daemon-rfkill.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-mutter.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-persistent-storage-android.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/63-md-raid-arrays.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/64-md-raid-assembly.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/65-libwacom.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-cd-sensors.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-lvm-metad.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-md-clustered-confirm-device.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-joystick.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-libfprint-2.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-memory.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-mouse.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-printers.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-touchpad.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/71-ipp-usb.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/71-power-switch-proliant.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/71-u-d-c-gpu-detection.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/73-special-net-names.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-broadmobi-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-cinterion-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-dell-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-dlink-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-fibocom-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-foxconn-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-gosuncn-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-haier-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-huawei-net-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-linktop-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-longcheer-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-mtk-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-nokia-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-qcom-soc.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-qdl-device-blacklist.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-quectel-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-sierra.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-simtech-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-telit-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-tplink-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-ublox-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-x22x-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/77-mm-zte-port-types.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/78-graphics-card.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-debian-compat.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-ifupdown.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-iio-sensor-proxy.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-libinput-device-groups.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-mm-candidate.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/81-net-dhcp.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/84-nm-drivers.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-brltty.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-hplj10xx.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-nm-unmanaged.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-bolt.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-console-setup.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-fwupd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-libinput-fuzz-override.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-nm-thunderbolt.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pipewire-alsa.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-cd-devices.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-dm-notify.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-hid.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-wup.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/96-e2scrub.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-libsane1.rules
Reading rules file: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'LENOVO'
value '[dmi/id]sys_vendor' is 'LENOVO'
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:29 GROUP 107
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules:8 Importing properties from results of builtin command 'hwdb --subsystem=input --lookup-prefix=evdev:'
event7: hwdb modalias key: "input:b0019v0000p0000e0000-e0,1,4,k8A,94,95,BA,BE,C0,C1,CA,CB,D4,E3,F0,F7,16C,1BD,1BE,232,27A,ram4,lsfw"
event7: No entry found from hwdb.
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules:8 Failed to run builtin 'hwdb --subsystem=input --lookup-prefix=evdev:': No data available
value '[dmi/id]modalias' is 'dmi:bvnLENOVO:bvrP9CN15WW:bd05/21/2024:br1.15:efr1.15:svnLENOVO:pn83DK:pvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:rvnLENOVO:rnLNVNB161216:rvrSDK0T76530WIN:cvnLENOVO:ct31:cvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:skuLENOVO_MT_83DK_BU_idea_FM_Yoga72-in-114AHP9:'
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules:18 Importing properties from results of builtin command 'hwdb 'evdev:name:Ideapad extra buttons:phys:ideapad/input0:ev:13:dmi:bvnLENOVO:bvrP9CN15WW:bd05/21/2024:br1.15:efr1.15:svnLENOVO:pn83DK:pvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:rvnLENOVO:rnLNVNB161216:rvrSDK0T76530WIN:cvnLENOVO:ct31:cvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:skuLENOVO_MT_83DK_BU_idea_FM_Yoga72-in-114AHP9:''
event7: No entry found from hwdb.
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules:18 Failed to run builtin 'hwdb 'evdev:name:Ideapad extra buttons:phys:ideapad/input0:ev:13:dmi:bvnLENOVO:bvrP9CN15WW:bd05/21/2024:br1.15:efr1.15:svnLENOVO:pn83DK:pvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:rvnLENOVO:rnLNVNB161216:rvrSDK0T76530WIN:cvnLENOVO:ct31:cvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:skuLENOVO_MT_83DK_BU_idea_FM_Yoga72-in-114AHP9:'': No data available
value '[dmi/id]modalias' is 'dmi:bvnLENOVO:bvrP9CN15WW:bd05/21/2024:br1.15:efr1.15:svnLENOVO:pn83DK:pvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:rvnLENOVO:rnLNVNB161216:rvrSDK0T76530WIN:cvnLENOVO:ct31:cvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:skuLENOVO_MT_83DK_BU_idea_FM_Yoga72-in-114AHP9:'
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules:23 Importing properties from results of builtin command 'hwdb 'evdev:name:Ideapad extra buttons:dmi:bvnLENOVO:bvrP9CN15WW:bd05/21/2024:br1.15:efr1.15:svnLENOVO:pn83DK:pvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:rvnLENOVO:rnLNVNB161216:rvrSDK0T76530WIN:cvnLENOVO:ct31:cvrYoga72-in-114AHP9:skuLENOVO_MT_83DK_BU_idea_FM_Yoga72-in-114AHP9:''
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-evdev.rules:23 Importing properties from results of builtin command 'keyboard'
event7: keyboard: mapping scan code 318 (0x13e) to key code 190 (0xbe)
event7: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x13e, and key code 190: Invalid argument
event7: keyboard: mapping scan code 319 (0x13f) to key code 247 (0xf7)
event7: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x13f, and key code 247: Invalid argument
event7: keyboard: mapping scan code 66 (0x42) to key code 193 (0xc1)
event7: keyboard: mapping scan code 67 (0x43) to key code 192 (0xc0)
event7: keyboard: mapping scan code 8 (0x8) to key code 190 (0xbe)
event7: keyboard: mapping scan code 13 (0xd) to key code 247 (0xf7)
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-input-id.rules:5 Importing properties from results of builtin command 'input_id'
input15: capabilities/ev raw kernel attribute: 13
input15: capabilities/abs raw kernel attribute: 0
input15: capabilities/rel raw kernel attribute: 0
input15: capabilities/key raw kernel attribute: 400000000000000 4000000000000 0 6000000000000000 100000000000 0 81000800100c03 4400000000300400 0 2
input15: properties raw kernel attribute: 0
event7: test_key: checking bit block 0 for any keys; found=1
event7: test_key: checking bit block 64 for any keys; found=1
event7: test_key: checking bit block 128 for any keys; found=1
event7: test_key: checking bit block 192 for any keys; found=1
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-input-id.rules:6 Importing properties from results of builtin command 'hwdb --subsystem=input --lookup-prefix=id-input:modalias:'
event7: hwdb modalias key: "input:b0019v0000p0000e0000-e0,1,4,k8A,94,95,BA,BE,C0,C1,CA,CB,D4,E3,F0,F7,16C,1BD,1BE,232,27A,ram4,lsfw"
event7: No entry found from hwdb.
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-input-id.rules:6 Failed to run builtin 'hwdb --subsystem=input --lookup-prefix=id-input:modalias:': No data available
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:35 Importing properties from results of builtin command 'path_id'
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:40 LINK 'input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.3-platform-VPC2004:00-event'
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules:6 Importing properties from '/etc/default/keyboard'
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/65-libwacom.rules:19 Importing properties from results of builtin command 'hwdb --subsystem=input '--lookup-prefix=libwacom:name:Ideapad extra buttons:''
event7: hwdb modalias key: "input:b0019v0000p0000e0000-e0,1,4,k8A,94,95,BA,BE,C0,C1,CA,CB,D4,E3,F0,F7,16C,1BD,1BE,232,27A,ram4,lsfw"
event7: No entry found from hwdb.
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/65-libwacom.rules:19 Failed to run builtin 'hwdb --subsystem=input '--lookup-prefix=libwacom:name:Ideapad extra buttons:'': No data available
event7: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-libinput-device-groups.rules:4 Importing properties from results of 'libinput-device-group /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input15/event7'
event7: Starting 'libinput-device-group /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input15/event7'
Successfully forked off '(spawn)' as PID 6988.
event7: 'libinput-device-group /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input15/event7'(out) 'LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=19/0/0:ideapad'
event7: Process 'libinput-device-group /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input15/event7' succeeded.
event7: Preserve permissions of /dev/input/event7, uid=0, gid=107, mode=0660
event7: Handling device node '/dev/input/event7', devnum=c13:71
event7: sd-device: Created db file '/run/udev/data/c13:71' for '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input15/event7'
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input15/event7
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event7
MAJOR=13
MINOR=71
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=input
TAGS=:power-switch:
KEYBOARD_KEY_13e=f20
KEYBOARD_KEY_13f=rfkill
KEYBOARD_KEY_42=f23
KEYBOARD_KEY_43=f22
KEYBOARD_KEY_08=f20
KEYBOARD_KEY_0d=rfkill
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.3-platform-VPC2004:00
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_3-platform-VPC2004_00
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.3-platform-VPC2004:00-event
XKBLAYOUT=us
BACKSPACE=guess
CURRENT_TAGS=:power-switch:
LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=19/0/0:ideapad
USEC_INITIALIZED=8675653
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.


Pop!_os is off topic on Ask Ubuntu, sorry

Ok. Is there a better forum to ask on? I'd just like to get this fixed.

There you go https://support.system76.com/

Thank you! I'll try there.
